# Azure policy - Cosmos DB SQL (Core) API - Restricting RU (Throughput) to not morethan 500

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-policy

I am trying to implement an azure policy for Cosmos DB (SQL API) to deny if the user is creating more than 500 throughputs.

Here I used JSON for the policy rule,

```
{
  "mode": "All",
    "policyRule":{
         "if": {
          "allOf": [
             {
                "field": "type",
                "equals": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases"
             },
             {
                "not": {
                    "field": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers/throughputSettings/default.resource.minimumThroughput",
                    "greater": 500
                }
             }
          ]
       },
       "then": {
          "effect": "deny"
       }
    }
}
```

this is not working and not able to find issue what am doing.

Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Your policy is set up to deny any throughput that are not greater than 500.

Comment: Hi Kemley. Thank you for responding. I am looking for the same